# Make a container element with a CSS style rule so that it expands around its floated content

Tags: html, css

I have to make a  container element with a style rule so that it expands around its floated content. I've already coded the html part, but in the CSS I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.

```
#container {
  position:relative;
}
```

Is what I was thinking of, but is this incorrect?

Comment: I think I answered my own question, but I'm not sure of its certainty.;
```css
#container {
clear: both;
content: "";
display: table;
}
```

Comment: Whelp, now my vertical nav bar displays boxes, which it should, but then it has either a padding or margin, which is causing the block display to continue past the buttons on the left. It displays fine on internet explorer, but messes up on google chrome.

Comment: We would need more of your code to help with this - and I'm not certain Webmasters is the best StackExchange for it - but in order to get your container to expand to the size of all its floated content you can use `overflow: hidden;` on it instead of the CSS in your first comment.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Ulthraun/pen/rPqoQW is the code and preview.

Comment: Can you update this question? Did you solve it, or just create a new question? I looked at the codepen and I really don't see what you are trying to accomplish. Help me out, please.